# Javascript "write" as function name and more

Tags: javascript, function

last time I found this piece of code included in some
tutorial. It just prints the numbers in the defined range.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function wypisz()
            {
                var liczba1 = document.getElementById("pole1").value;
                var liczba2 = document.getElementById("pole2").value;
                var napis = "";

                for (i=liczba1; i<=liczba2; i++)
                {
                    napis = napis + i + " ";
                }
                document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = napis;
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" id="pole1" />
        <input type="text" id="pole2" />
        <input type="submit" value="Pokaż" onclick="wypisz()"/>

        <div id="wynik"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

1. When I change the function name "wypisz()" to "write()" and I press the button, the page turn white and the never-ending loading starts. 
   Does it mean the "write" is reserved as the global function name? I can't see it here:
   [JavaScript Reserved Words](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)
2. In the same code, when I define the range <2-9> in the first input text filed and <11-19> in the second one, nothing happens. But, when I add zero in front of the first number it works. What does it mean?

This is my workaround (I added a function to count from up to down):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function _write()
        {
            var number1 =document.getElementById("field1").value;
            var number2 =document.getElementById("field2").value;
            var tab=new Array();
            var number=Math.abs(number2-number1);

            if(number1<10 && number1>1) number1=0+number1;//add zero


                for(i=0;i<=number;i++)
                {
                    tab.push(number1);
                    if(number1<number2)
                    ++number1;          
                    else
                    --number1;         //bigger-smaller
                }


            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=tab.join(" ");
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="field1" />
    <input type="text" id="field2" />
    <input type="submit" value="SHOW" onclick="_write()"/>

    <div id="result"></div>

</body>
```

I thought: "Problem resolved". Then I saw this:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZioj.jpg)

Comment: `write()` seems to be calling `document.write()` instead of your own function.

Comment: @Barmar I can never find where it is written in spec, but _JavaScript_ written in attributes has `__proto__ === Object.prototype` and some behaviour as if `with (document) with (this) { /* code */ }`, and some more things in there too which I can't pin down right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do "getElementByid" on the text field, I believe it is returning the value as a string. This is why adding a "0" before the first number changes the answer, because string comparisons compare the characters from left to right, and it will cast the 0 to a string before adding it since the variable is already a string.

You'll probably want to cast your value to an int. you can do something like "number1 = parseInt(number1)" or even just wrap the entire document.getelement function in a "parseInt" command. This should work as you are expecting it to work.

EDIT: to answer the question about write, it looks like it's a DOM function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

It's not reserved, but it looks like if you call the function after the page has been loaded, it'll replace all the HTML in the page. Your onclick function is likely binding to the document's write function rather than the one in your script.

Answer (score 0):

```js
            function wypisz()
            {
                var liczba1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("pole1").value);
                var liczba2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("pole2").value);
                var napis = "";
                for (i=liczba1; i<=liczba2; i++)
                {
                    napis = napis + i + " ";
                console.log('inseide');
    }
    
                document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = napis;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question only, when you define an event handler in HTML by setting an element's `onClick` attribute to a snippet of javascipt code (or any other 'onEventName' attribute), the browser creates a function for your code snippet, **but not in global scope**.

HTML event handler functions are given an object scope chain which searches properties of the object the handler was set on (an <INPUT> element in your case) followed by searching parent objects in turn until the top of the DOM is reached, followed by searching global variables to find the value of an identifier.

So when you call `write` from HTML, `document.write` is found in the scope chain of the handler before reaching your function of the same name in global scope. If you added the handler using `element.addEventListener` it should work as expected.

The origin of the scope chain is that Netscape thought properties of a form and the document object should be in the scope chain of event handler functions to simplify programming. Searching every parent node between an element and the document object arose later during browser wars of the late 1990s.

See also: "Javascript the definitive guide" O'Reilly, section "19.1.6. Scope of Event Handlers"